# How do I parse a string (with commas and the sign at the end, ie. "3,246,928-") in C#?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double

I've got a string that looks like

```
3,246,928-
```

And I'd like to turn this into a C# double.

Is there a preset format that will parse this as a negative double for me?

I tried

```
double parsedValue = Double.Parse("3,246,928-");
```

And get an Exception "Input string was not in a correct format."

Is there a way to do this *without* manually checking for a negative symbol at the end, stripping it out, stripping the commas, etc..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum to indicate which styles are permitted in the input string:

```
var input = "3,246,928-";

var res = Double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign);

Console.WriteLine(res);  // -3246928
```

It may also be a good idea to use `TryParse` instead:

```
var input = "3,246,928-";

if (Double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign, null, out var result))
    Console.WriteLine(result);  // -3246928
```

Comment: All detailed in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2